# How can I append fitted GAM model values back to each group?

Tags: r, dplyr, mgcv

I have daily observations for some data (`Var1`) over three years across several sites (`siteID`) and have fit a generalized additive model (GAM) for each site based on the day of year (`DoY`). How can I append the fitted gam values back to the original data frame?

Here is some example data:

```
library(mgcv)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = 2190))
x <- c("siteID", "DoY", "Var1", "gam_fitted_var1")
colnames(df) <- x
df[1:1095,1] <- rep("A",1095)
df[1096:2190,1] <- rep("B",1095)
df$DoY <- rep(seq(from = 1, to = 365, by = 1),6)
set.seed(123)
a <- 10  # amplitude
b = 2*pi/365
c = 1
d = rnorm(365,2,2)
aa = 4
dd = rnorm(365,4,1)
e <- rep(seq(1,365,1),3)
y1 <- a*sin(b*(e-c))+d
y2 <- aa*sin(b*(e-c))+dd
df[1:1095,3] <- y1
df[1096:2190,3] <- y2
```

I fit the GAMs for each group as follows:

```
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(siteID) %>%
  do(gam_mod = gam(Var1 ~ s(DoY, bs = 'cc'), data = .)) %>%
  ungroup
```

How can I take the 'fitted.values' from the GAM output and append them back to the original data frame (`df`)? I know how to do this manually as follows below, but my true dataset has 100's of groups (i.e.,`siteID`) and I would like to avoid manually doing this for each site.

```
df[1:1095,4] <- df2[[2]][[1]][["fitted.values"]]
df[1096:2190,4] <- df2[[2]][[2]][["fitted.values"]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sapply` to extract `"fitted.values"` from each `gam_mod` and add as a new column.

```
df$gam_fitted_var1 <- c(sapply(df2$gam_mod, `[[`, "fitted.values"))
```

Comment: You're better off using the `fitted()` method to extract these rather than grabbing the specific component

Comment: @GavinSimpson I have tried doing `fitted(df2$gam_mod)` but the output is `NULL`. Could you elaborate on how it would be used in this example for extracting the fitted.values out of a list of GAM model outputs? Also what are the benefits of this approach?

Comment: If `df2$gam_mod` inherits from class `"gam"` then this should work, but it's not clear to me what your `do()` step results in. You need to do follow the answer and `sapply()` but instead of using `[[` to subset, use `fitted`, as in `sapply(df2$gam_mod, fitted)`, `gam_mod` clearly isn't the fitted model but a list of models I presume?

Comment: @GavinSimpson Yes, the `do()` step results in a list of gam models and doing the `c(sapply(df2$gam_mod, fitted))` provided the same result as that described by @RonakShah.  What's odd about both answers is that when I apply them to my true dataset with 100+ gam models neither answer works. I get an error that the existing data has x rows while the assigned data has y rows (the y value being the number of gam models produced by the `do()` function). I might be able to fix that with a for loop and will post answer when I have it.